# Categories instance methods do not invoke

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, methods, categories

I have a class(Core Data Generated):

```
@interface Place : NSManagedObject

 @property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * title;
 @property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * subtitle;
 @property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * latitude;
 @property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * longitude;

@end
@implementation Place

@dynamic title;
@dynamic subtitle;
@dynamic latitude;
@dynamic longitude;

@end
```

Adn a category for it:

```
@interface Place (Create)
+ (Place *)placeWithTitle:(NSString *)title
        inManagedObjectContext:(NSManagedObjectContext *)context;

+(Place *) placeWithTitle:(NSString *)title andSubtitle:(NSString *)subtitle inManagedObjectContext:(NSManagedObjectContext *)context;
+(Place *) placeWithCoordinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D) coordinate inManagedObjectContext:(NSManagedObjectContext *)context;
- (void) setLattitudeAndLongitudeByCoordinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D) coordinate;


- (CLLocationCoordinate2D) coordinate;
@end
```

In this category a have to instance methods:

```
- (void) setLattitudeAndLongitudeByCoordinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D) coordinate
{
    self.latitude=[NSNumber numberWithDouble:coordinate.latitude];//break point HERE
    self.longitude=[NSNumber numberWithDouble:coordinate.longitude];
}

-(CLLocationCoordinate2D) coordinate
{
    CLLocationCoordinate2D coord;//break point HERE
    coord.latitude=[self.latitude doubleValue];
    coord.longitude=[self.longitude doubleValue];
    return coord;
}
```

As you see i have to breakpoints there. Now, then i call those methods

```
#import "Place+Create.h"

-(void)someMethod
{
    [self.place setLattitudeAndLongitudeByCoordinate:coordiante];
}
```

It never seem to reach those breakpoints inside the method setLattitudeAndLogitudeByCoordinate,
and debug shows that it even doesn't call them! Why?

Comment: Is `someMethod` ever reached? If not, then your problem is somewhere else. If it is reached then `self.place` obviously is `nil`.

Comment: I am repeating this in my answer to prevent this question from remaining unanswered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is `someMethod` ever reached? Check that using a breakpoint or an extra `NSLog` at its head.

If not, then your problem is somewhere else as your program flow is different than you expected it to be.

If it is reached then `self.place` obviously is `nil`. That means you never initialized it and again, your program flow is different than you thought it would be.